# Wordpress PHP Query custom post type for current archive user

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to render all the posted "custom post type content" content from a "xx" user. 
I have been trying to accomplish this, but of course, something is wrong. 
that's why Im here, to learn how to make things right.

I have tried with this code: works. shows all the posts, but not from the author. **How can I define wich author's post should be queried?**

I can render the custom post types but I need to query only the author. Im making some sort of customized "archive" page.

```
               <?php 
    query_posts(array( 
        'post_type' => 'video_listing',
        'showposts' => 10 
    ) );  
?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
        <p><?php echo get_the_excerpt(); ?></p>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to extend your `query_posts()` function call with the `author` or `author_name` parameter.

```
query_posts(array( 
    'post_type' => 'video_listing',
    'author' => 1
    'showposts' => 10 
));
```

According to the example above `1` is the ID of the author you like to filter for.